# Best practice on definitions: description vs paragraph and others

Tags: paragraphs, description

I would like to define some technical terms (e.g. precision, repeatability, error, accuracy, ...).
I have seen tutorials doing it in two different ways:

```
\begin{description}
    \item[term] describing text
\end{description}
```

or

```
\paragraph{term}
describing text
```

What are the differences and which way is suited for what application and might there be an even better option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `description` environment conceptually is an `itemize`-like environment, so a "list", used to list some items, enhancing their names and displaying their descriptions so that they are separated and indented from the normal text (hence enhanced), and more clearly visible.

`\paragraph` is a sectioning command, thus indicating a division in your document, which can usually be used to insert some notes, or some small paragraphs which talk briefly about a specific topic. The spacing between the word(s) that start the paragraph (i.e. the ones between the braces) is bigger than the one used in `description`. Mind that for long descriptions, these flow like the normal text and are not displayed in an indented environment.

I would go with `description`, which is more compact and enhances the definitions, and usually never use the `paragraph` environment, unless there are some remarks about the text above them that I want to attract the reader to.

**EDIT**

I'm adding an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
 \item[item1:] a somewhat long long description about your item and all about it and look how pretty it is displayed like this
  \item[item2:] a somewhat long long description about your item and all about it and look how pretty it is displayed like this
  \end{description}

  \paragraph{item1} a somewhat long long description about your item and all about it and look how pretty it is displayed like this

  \paragraph{item2} a somewhat long long description about your item and all about it and look how pretty it is displayed like this
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about page breaking (favoring inside or inbetween item-breaking), page filling and referencing behavior?

Comment: @n4pk I'm not an expert on page breaking, I think that both commands are prone to between-item breaking. About referencing it depends: paragraph are, I think, more easily referenced, but you have to number them... If you have _that_ much amount of terms, maybe you're interested in creating a glossary?

Comment: You can keep the *semantics* of a `description` list and customize the format if you don't like the default LaTeX format. Look at the `enumitem` package.

Answer (score 2):

I tested `description` and `paragraph` a bit myself and realized, that in general `description` should be used. Here is a small comparison:

- As seen in [Moriambars answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362255/56139): `description` indents all the trailing text lines, whereas `paragraph` only has indentation for the first line.
- `description` fits better between leading and trailing text. For `paragraph` it is hard to see, whether the trailing text is part of the description or not. (So you may use paragraph only, if your whole section is about definitions.)
- The descriptors for `description`can NOT line-break; `paragraph` titles can.
- `paragraph` entries may (obviously) end up in the table of contents (if `tocdepth` is set accordingly)
- You can not reference the descriptor name (as far as I know), only the page or the section, in which the `description` is included; but you can `nameref` the `paragraph`.

I experience once, that all the `description` items tried desperately to fill the page, creating large white spaces in between them. Here is was not able to reproduce this behavior.

---

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents\newpage
\section{Definitions with the \texttt{description} environment} \label{sec:sec1}
Here is just some text to fill up some space in the front, to make the document look like some common tex example. I need to continue to write senseless text, so the space will be taken from the page.

\begin{description}
\item[item 1:\label{des:item1}]Just a little short text here.
\item[super-duper-very-extra-mega-long item which doesn't line-break] Obviously \texttt{description}-descriptors can not line break... Very sad.
\item[s.i.:] Here comes a very short item, but it should also have a reasonably long describing text.
\item[item four] Just some random text, which should take up some space right behind the item-element.
\item Here one example without a descriptor.\\ Can we have manual line-breaks inside the description? Oh yes, we can!\\ I remember some case, were there was strange spacing between list-items, trying to fill up the page.

But apparently it does not occur in this case.
\item[last item] Let's see one more item in the list.
%\item[last last item] There is always a last \texttt{item}.
\end{description}

Juuuust a little more text to fill a line after all the describing stuff above. And another line allmost filled! The line is not filled yet, so I have to write some more. And more... AND MOOOORE!! So much text! This is an incredibly long text, where latex has no place to simply page-break it. Let's see how it performs.

\section{Definitions with the \texttt{paragraph} instruction}
Just an introductional text-line.

\paragraph[apparently paragraphed items may end up in the table of contents]{Paragraphed item 1}\label{par:item1}
I am tired of inventing text. \texttt{Blindtext}, help me out here! Ohh.... no blindtext... Damn. Now I have to fill the text again by myself! Ooooh byyyy myyyyy seeeeelft. Don't wanna be... Ah. Were you singing along?
%\blindtext

\paragraph{super-duper-extra-mega-very-very-extremely-long item which does line-break}
A somewhat very longer description.
\paragraph{} Lets have an empty one, just as we had before. Just to see how it looks. How about manual line-breaking?\\Mom, can I touch it? Only if you wash your hands afterwards!
\paragraph{s.o.:} or a short one!

Does this text belong to the last item? Who knows? Nobody does! You just can't really tell. Too bad. It almost looked good.
\section{Referencing (with \texttt{cleveref})}
\cref{des:item1} on \cpageref{des:item1}. Does not work properly... \texttt{nameref} crashes.\\
\cref{par:item1}, \nameref{par:item1} on \cpageref{par:item1}. Does also not work perfectly. But at least \texttt{nameref} works.
\end{document}
```